# Can I get Solr/Sunspot to return all results, plus the previous and next?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Each record in my database is a line from a movie. When a line is searched for, I'd like to return not only that line, but the line before and after it. Right now, I'm doing this by defining `next` and `previous` methods on the `Line` model, which return the record with the next/previous ID (they are sorted by ID so that's easy), but that leads to tons of database hits per page.

Ideally I'd like to be able to tell Solr to include the next/previous records with each result and just issue the one query. But I can't find anything in the docs that describes how to do that.

(Each line has associated data like a screencap and timestamp, so it's not practical to just store the entire transcript in one record and return a substring around it.)